# Listen VPN connected status changes in an internal website, without using any api in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application that is an internal application, works only if user connected to VPN.

Issue: When user load application at that time user connected to VPN, but later in mid of using application, user disconnected from VPN may be manually or due to bad network connection. at that time I want to detect that change in application and show that to user to connect with VPN. Is there any way to listen the VPN connection status change in ReactJs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching about that. Until now, the best approach I fond is to have simple endpoint in our backend protected by our VPN, so we can check if it is accessible from time to time, if it respond with 403, it is down.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).